# Use the Tor service without using Tor browser?

Tags: tor-install

I just want to use the tor service in my ubuntu 16.04 and use the tor network without the browser of tor because i want to use it in palemoon browser. How i could do it? Some way to use tor service directly? Which are the steps ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend that as unlike Tor-browser, even browsers known for security (like Brave) do in fact connect to agencies, but if you just want an answer, try something like:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
sudo systemctl enable tor
sudo systemctl start tor
```

In Palemoon, go to the Tools -> Settings -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings. Choose Manual Proxy configuration. Socks Host: 127.0.0.1 Port 9050. Check: Use Proxy to perform DNS Queries